# What are the names of all of the monster taxa? I'm planning to convert some into booze

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Vegetable, Demon, Undead, Animal, etc. - does anyone know what ALL of the monster taxa are? I'm working on a Chef skill for brewing and frying chunks of live monsters in combat, damaging them and creating consumables.

You'd think the taxa would be listed at one of the several Dredmor wikis that exist, but it appears not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The valid taxa are:

- Animal (ie, Diggle)
- Construct (ie, Golem)
- Demon (ie, Djinn)
- Other (ie, Blobby)
- Undead (ie, Deth)
- Vegetable (ie, Pumpkinn (and yes, that's how it's spelled.))

I pulled this data from the XML file (monDB.xml) that came with the game, so it should represent all the possible monster types.

Comment: Weird, I thought one of the talking points of the Diggle God expansion was that it contained 12 new monster types. Well that simplifies things; thanks!

Comment: @Gumbz, yes, there are more monster *types*, but they all fit into these groups.